# Maximum Storage for Survivor Bases

Tags: state-of-decay, state-of-decay-breakdown

In Breakdown, you play over, and over with increasing difficulty. One of the consequences of taking your inventory is that it quickly fills up with rubbish.

I need to clear some of this space but all of the survivor encampments are quite a distance, so I don't want to make many trips if I can't get rid of most of it.

Assuming that you have enough Influence to keep taking weapons / items out, is there a limit to how many items can be put into a survivor encampments chest?  I know these don't carry over, I just want a way to get rid of lots of items without loosing all the Influence taking them out (and the time wasted driving between the Trucking Warehouse and the Church).

I have had it stop me putting items in before, but I didn't keep a note of how many I'd put in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You've probably known this, but your base's [Supply Locker](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Supply_Locker) and the [outposts](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Outposts)' Supply Lockers are linked. When you scavenge, put an outpost near the scavenging area and dump the new items there, which is much faster than driving all the way back to your home site. You can clear out your locker in any of the outposts, not just at the home site.
- Regarding your main question, the Supply Locker is limited to 256 slots/stacks. Each weapon and backpack takes 1 slot, while ammunition and other consumables have varying stack sizes. When you hit 256, you cannot put in anything that creates a new stack. The size of Enclaves' supply locker is the same as your home site's.